# FormIO + Angular - Reply an input on change

Tags: angular, input, view, formio

I want to reply the value of an input in an other.
For example:

```
<input name="n" >Name</input>
<input name="n2" >Name2</input>
```

And i want to keep the change of the value from "Name" and put it to "Name2".

Inside an Angular template i have put this declaration:

```
<formio [form]="formProva" (submit)="onSubmit($event)" [submission]="myJSON" (change)="onChange($event)"> </formio>
```

where:

1. formProva -> the Form.IO JSON schema of the form i want to represent
2. onChange(param) -> In this function i:

   1. keep the JSON schema of the form from 'param'
   2. keep the modified value from "Name" navigating in 'param'
   3. Assign the value from "Name" in 'param' to "Name2" in 'myJSON'.

My problem is that nothing change in the view, but:

```
console.log(param);
console.log(myJSON);
```

show the correct modification in the json schema.
Anyone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

We have similar problem here. We call an API to get values for other fields to be filled after id number is filled and everything works fine apart from the fact that the view in form renderer is not updated. The values are assigned to the fields (after pressing Submit button everything's there) but they just don't show in the renderer after being downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Old post I know but if you want to update the form UI and/or its submission you need to use [refresh]="refreshForm" with an event EventEmitter.
The docs here https://github.com/formio/angular-formio/wiki/Form-Renderer says that but I've often still experienced issues where the UI or the submission fails to update even with the EventEmitter.

Also I don't believe that the from component watches the form JSON and the form JSON dose not always sync up with the UI - the dynamic hide/show system is a prime suspect in this regard.